# Why instanceof Map returns false?

Tags: javascript, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I am using Draft.js plugin [Mention](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/mention).

For `editorState.content.entityMap.mention`, I can successfully get value by

```
mention.get('address')
```

But why I check whether it is `Map` by

```
console.log('mention', mention);
console.log('mention instanceof Map', mention instanceof Map);
```

it returns `false`? Note the console shows `mention` is Map.

[image]

Comment: I would imagine it's because there are two different `Map` classes, with either one or both a polyfill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write instanceof Map it refers to this native [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). I dug through the [Draft.js source code](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/blob/master/draft-js-mention-plugin/src/index.js) (line 2) and found that they use a different kind of map from [this library](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). So when you compare them it isn't the same.